# Advantages of using WSDL4j over DOM api

Tags: java, web-services, dom, wsdl4j

For WSDL handling, we can use [org.w3c.dom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html) api. We can parse the WSDL as an XML and navigate through different nodes and create different elements.

Then what is the advantage of WSDL4j that it is preferred over DOM api for `web services` construction?